# Windows Phone 8 manual application exit c++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I am writing a C++ DirectX application without XAML for Windows Phone 8. I have met on difficulty. In the certifications requirements it is mentioned that:

> "Verify that either the app closes without error, or allows the user
>   to confirm closing   the app with a menu or dialog."

When on the main screen user presses back button I show the yes-no dialog. When user presses Yes how should I make the app exit?

In this topic there are some solutions but they seem to work only with XAML.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/fdedf8f6-e691-4df6-92c7-ed3dc97bddc0/

How should I close the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that MSDN forum link it seems that the back key press logic in C++/DirectX works in the same way as C#/XAML.

I.e. If you set the handled flag `command->Handled = true;` in the Back key press handler the application framework will not close the app.

If you don't set the flag  then the application framework will close the app.

Comment: In event handler I do `command->Handled = true` so as to show yes-no dialog. If I won't do so the app will terminate without asking the user. But when user press yes no event is passed to the handler so this approach won't work.

Comment: Ah that figures if you're displaying your own UI and not just a .NET MessageBox (which is a blocking call somewhat confusingly).

Comment: I wonder if you can make the BackKeyPress asynchronous and wait for your custom UI Yes/No handler without deadlocking the UI...

Comment: I so a good solution when to make program exit GoBack action was called. But I see no way to do it without XAML.